# Use .htaccess to force HTTPS only on 1 page & 1 directory?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

We need to force HTTPS only for one specific page and one directory, i.e. /login.php and anything in the /forum directory.  All other pages on the site should be forced into HTTP (even if manually requested as HTTPS).

I'm hitting roadblocks getting this to work via .htaccess... can anyone help?  Thanks so much!

Comment: You know it's insecure to do so? If you only use https on a few pages, you are vulnerable to man in the middle, and you cant use HSTS (which is the only protection against sslstrip attacks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rewriteRules :

```
RewriteEngine on


#force https for /login.php and /forum
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(login\.php|forum/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R]
#redirect everything else to http if requested as https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^((?!login\.php|forum/.*).*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like I also need to have the final RewriteRule ignore all .js, .css, .jpg, .gif and .png files as well or my site design breaks.  But when I modified your last line this doesn't seem to work:

    RewriteRule ^((?!login\.php|\.css|\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|\.js|forum/.*).*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R]

Comment: Your modified code does not match **file.css** it just matches **.css** . Remove the carat **^** to solve this.

Comment: When I remove the carat it then breaks the login.php page (it redirects to ogin.php)

Comment: or try this pattern **^((?!login\.php|forum/.*|.*\.css|.*\.js).*)$**